# Any Python Script to Save Websites Like Firefox?

Tags: python

I am tired of clicking "File" and then "Save Page As" in Firefox when I want to save some websites.

Is there any script to do this in Python? I would like to save the pictures and css files so that when I read it offline, it looks normal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use wget

wget -m -k -E [url]

```
-E, --html-extension        save HTML documents with `.html' extension.
-m,  --mirror             shortcut for -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing.
-k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML point to local files.
```

Comment: Thanks this was the most helpful, but I found out that the "-p" flag is the one that is needed. "wget -k -p www.google.com"

Comment: Be aware that wget is not able to transform URIs in JavaScript and CSS. It doesn't even transform things like `<script src="http://host.tld/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>` and `background:url(http://host.tld/images/image.png)`.

Comment: How this saved a dynamically generated PHP page I do not know, but it did. Complete with CSS and images. Great Stuff, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

probably a tool like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is more appropriate for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-Python answer and I'm not sure what your machine is running, but have you consider using a [site ripper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522290/suggestions-for-a-site-ripper) such as wget?

```
import os
cmd = 'wget <parameters>'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: The combination of the above answer and yours makes a great combination for saving a WebPage, It even worked with a dynamic PHP generated page. I used it in Jupyter Notebook. I use Jupyter Notebook for all my editing and uploads to my VPS. I wanted a tool to save a PHP generated page then upload it as a static HTML . This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like Cobbal stated, this is largely what wget is designed to do. I believe there's some flags/arguments that you can set to make it download the entire page, CSS + all. I suggest just alias-ing into something more convenient to type, or tossing it into a quick script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)?