# Good apps I could use to store a page locally?

Tags: python, html, linux, caching, screen-scraping

**I really need to find a reliable way in order to store a web page locally, with all it's dependencies** e.g. html, css stylesheets, javascript, etc...

A python library would be awesome, a CLI would be great too. Also would this type of app/library have a standardized name?

---

**Any suggestions guys?** =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) in the past to good effect (available for Windows, Linux, & OS X). It has a [C API](http://www.httrack.com/html/dev.html) and there is also a [third-party Python wrapper](http://code.google.com/p/httrack-py/) available.

Also see this question: [Any Python Script to Save Websites Like Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035825/any-python-script-to-save-websites-like-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/overview.html) which is fairly simple and efficient:
it is a bit more than a python library...